# "Two [men] {get / were / got / } involved in a fistfight"

Tags: past-tense, headlinese

I saw this post title in Reuters Facebook page

***Two Ukrainian lawmakers get involved in a fistfight after one accuses the other of having ties to Russia***

https://www.facebook.com/Reuters/videos/1288849304468756/?hc_ref=PAGES_TIMELINE

And I'm wondering if it possible to say it in different way like:

1. Two Ukrainian lawmakers **were involved** in a fistfight after one accuses the other of having ties to Russia.
2. Two Ukrainian lawmakers **got involved** in a fistfight after one accuses the other of having ties to Russia.
3. Two Ukrainian lawmakers **involved** in a fistfight after one accuses the other of having ties to Russia.

Answer (score 5):

The form with "were involved" is the most ordinary and common form of this. The form with "got involved" is also perfectly normal, but some might regard this use of the verb "get" as colloquial, and avoid it in writing.

The form with just "involved" is not a sentence. It might occur in a headline, but I would expect other elisions (e.g. of the article "a").

In the first two, "accuses" is odd in the second half, and I would expect "accused". In the "headline" example, "accuses" is fine.